# How to add a single field into two different tables at a same time: Database

Tags: database, forms, foreign-keys

I have two tables like: 1-Company 2-Company_members both have a same column company_id, so i want at the time submitting the form to register company it will also add the comopany_id in company_members table also,

I have tried to make it by foreign key but no success.

I need guide on this: Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The company ID field is the primary key of Company table and the one on company members is a foreign key. The form that registers the company just registers the company and the one that registers the members should be different. So when you register the company you just insert in the Company table and when you register a company mamber in the form you need to have a field showing the companies and when the user chooses the company you need to take its ID and put it in the foreign key field in company_members table.

Comment: Actually both tables are using the same form. but i have separated the fields for both the tables. both tables are updating on one form submitting..@DrCIH

Comment: What does the company_members contain and why do you want the company ID values in it?

Comment: Company_members will contain the members for that company we are registering. it is needed because we want to specify which member blongs to which company